# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException in testng

Tags: selenium, testng, parallel-testing

Facing  an error

`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id`

when tried to execute below script in testng and all opened browsers are not closing

```
public class Sample {

  WebDriver driver = null;

  @BeforeMethod

  public void setUp() {

    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "dataProvider")

  public void test(String url, String arg1, String arg2) throws InterruptedException {

    driver.get(url);

    System.out.println("driver.getTitle()" + driver.getTitle() + "arg1 :" + arg1 + "arg2 :" + arg2);

  }

  @AfterMethod

    public void tearDown() {

    driver.close();

    driver.quit();

  }

  @DataProvider(parallel = true)

  public String[][] dataProvider() {

    return new String[][] { { "https://github.com/", "alex", "India" },

      { "https://jenkins.io/download/", "Krishna", "UK" },

      { "https://www.facebook.com/", "Bhupesh", "USA" } };

    }

  }
```

Its launching url perfectly but it is not closing the all the opened browsers 
please help

Comment: Can you share your testng.xml also?

Comment: What does `WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();` do?

Comment: Why do you have `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()`? `driver.quit()` will kill the driver as well as close the browser.

Comment: @Pratik I think you are right